# Link two instances of Apache Archiva

Tags: archiva

We have two distributed dev teams. Each with it's own Archiva instance. Each team deploys artifacts into their own repository. I'd like to configure each of these Archiva instances so that they each can discover artifacts from the other.

I set up Proxy Connectors on each Archiva.

- Archiva A -> Archiva B
- Archiva B -> Archiva A

But when someone requests an artifact one of the two Archiva's hangs, requiring the service to be rebooted.

Is this Proxy Connector configuration creating an infinite loop? Perhaps I'm confused by how they work. If they shouldn't be configured in this manner, how would I solve my original problem of two Archiva's sharing artifacts?

Answer (score 1):

are you using some black/white lists to limit the proxying to only your company groupId ?
Hangs but nothing in the logs ?

Comment: This is a good idea, however the groupId is common between both sites so this won't work for us.